# Sort Python list by first two characters and return the one that had more occurrences

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
list = [('Confidence', 1), ('Malicious', 1), ('Gen3', 1), ('Filecoder', 1), ('Score', 1), ('Wanacrypt', 1), ('Engine', 1), ('Eqmtct', 1), ('Wannacryptor', 1), ('Aiqcm', 1), ('Wannacrypt', 1), ('Wcryg', 1), ('Cbvj', 1), ('Farfli', 1), ('Wanna', 1), ('Wisdomeyes', 1), ('Wannacry', 1), ('High', 1), ('Static', 1), ('Wcry', 1)]
```

> return = [ WanaCrypt Wanna WannaCry WannaCrypt WannaCryptor ]

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post the error you're running into?

Comment: Is the integer in each tuple supposed to mean something?

Comment: Please update the question with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you right, the numerical values on your tuples list don't affect your result, as your only looking for strings that begin with the most common first two characters.

The following code will do that:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

# Your list
tuples = [
    ('Confidence', 1), ('Malicious', 1), ('Gen3', 1), ('Filecoder', 1),
    ('Score', 1), ('Wanacrypt', 1), ('Engine', 1), ('Eqmtct', 1),
    ('Wannacryptor', 1), ('Aiqcm', 1), ('Wannacrypt', 1), ('Wcryg', 1),
    ('Cbvj', 1), ('Farfli', 1), ('Wanna', 1), ('Wisdomeyes', 1),
    ('Wannacry', 1), ('High', 1), ('Static', 1), ('Wcry', 1)
]

# Calculate which initial is more ocurrent
values = [t[0] for t in tuples]
initials = defaultdict(int)
for v in values:
    initials[v[:2]] += 1
initial_str = Counter(initials).most_common()[0][0]

# Creates a list with values that start with the most occurrent initial string 
results = [v for v in values if v.startswith(initial_str)]
print(results)
```